# Ruby on Rails Blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blogs

Does anybody know a basic plugin/gem that will allow me to quickly set up a blog in Rails.
I would like it to have a WYSIWYG editor that allows image upload and basic editing.

All the Google results I checked out were tutorials to creating a blog in Rails.

I'm not looking to roll out my own solution, I'm looking for something that was already made, like Wordpress, but for Rails.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for a plugin/gem to be embedded in your application like in django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [Mephisto](http://github.com/halorgium/mephisto)

**PS:** Search for "rails blog engine" in Google and you will find many other hits.

Answer (score 1):

[Mephisto](http://mephistoblog.com/) and [typo](http://wiki.github.com/fdv/typo/) used to be the mainstream, but there are many new kids on the block these days.